# How can I transfer this ROI value inside RateOI function value to the contract itself and the contract Balance gets updated

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, address.transfer, transfer

```
contract RATE {
    function contractBalance() public returns(uint){
        return  address(this).balance ;

        // store = address(this).balance;
        // console.log(store);
        // store = store+ROI;
        // console.log(store);
        // address(this).balance = store;
        //  console.log(address(this).balance);
        // return address(this).balance;
    }

    function RateOI() public returns(uint){
        // require(userRegistered()== true);
        // require(balances[msg.sender]>0);

        ROI = (balances[msg.sender]*rate*1)/100;
        
        
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What's the ROI value? ether, tokens, a number, ... A contract cannot modify someone else balance, it can only transfer from its own balance. It could receive ethers in the receive function of if the function is payable..

Comment: ROI value is inside the function RateOI

Comment: I am asking how can i transfer this ROI value to contract Balance

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what are you trying to achieve. To make a contract transfer its own ether you could use `recipientAddres.transfer(weiAmount);`.